# How to pass angular 2 variable's value to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZtZF.png)

This is my image
I want to pass "c.name" and "c.image_Url" in onclick function as given in image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let c of categories" (click)="selectedCategory(c.name,c.image_url)">

     //<---note (click) event - angular2 way element's click binding
     ....

</div>
```

In component,

```
selectedCategory(value1,value2){
 console.log(value1);
 console.log(value2);
}
```

Comment: I am already using so many nested div so adding more will trouble me! I'm wondering that if there is any simpler solution :-)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me :-)